# How to cast from NSDictionary to Dictionary ? swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3

please have a look at the bellow code:

```
class A{


   class func func1(params post_params:NSDictionary!){

                let post_paramsValue =  post_params as? Dictionary<String,Any>!
                self.func2(params: post_paramsValue)
    }

    class func func2(post_params:Dictionary<String,Any?>!)
}
############### OBJECTIVE C ###############
[A func1:nil];
```

on swift 3 the code crash on `self.func2(params: post_paramsValue)` with this exception:

**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

although it run on swift 2

1. func2 can accept nil values! so why it crashes ?
2. why i don't receive build error if there is a problem with casting `Dictionary<String,Any>!` to `Dictionary<String,Any?>!` ?

**EDIT1:**

Why the bellow code doesn't crash ?

```
NSMutableDictionary *infoToUpload = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
infoToUpload[@"lookitChatId"] = @"";
[A func1:nil];
```

**EDIT2:**

I think i should write the func1 in this way to make sure that the code won't crash: (i don't why ?)

```
class func func1(params post_params:NSDictionary!){

                  if  let post_paramsValue =  post_params as? Dictionary<String,Any>!{
                           self.func2(params: post_paramsValue)
                   }else{

                         self.func2(params: nil)
                     }

        }
```

Comment: Objective-C does not allow `nil` values in dictionaries **at all**, and even in Swift they are silly because they defeat the recommended syntax to remove a key by setting the value to `nil`.

Comment: @vadian thank you for your comment, all my code is already use func2 with Dictionary<String,Any?> i can't change it. what's your suggestion ?

Comment: @vadian can you please answer my two questions.

Comment: I can't answer the questions definitely but consider to use dictionaries with non-optional values when bridging to ObjC.

Comment: @vadian this code was working on swift2 , i don't understand what's happened !!!

Comment: @vadian i've edit the questions , can you please tell me why the new code doesn't crash ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is you code but with no crash.

```
class A {
    class func func1(params post_params: NSDictionary!){
        let post_paramsValue = post_params as? Dictionary<String,Any>
        self.func2(post_params: post_paramsValue)
    }
    class func func2(post_params:Dictionary<String,Any>!) {
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i need to func2(params: Dictionary<String,Any?>!)  is there other suggestions?

Comment: Sure! Use `Dictionary<String, Any>` with value `NSNull` for `nil` values.

Comment: Add null-value example: `params["key"] = NSNull()`

Comment: thank you again, but the problem is func2 is called also by swift , i can't change it to func2(params: Dictionary<String,Any>?) . all my code is already using it as func2(post_params:Dictionary<String,Any?>!)

Comment: I've edit code in my answer. Check it for fix your issue.

Comment: thank you very much, but that doesn't help i need to declare func2 as  func2(post_params:Dictionary<String,Any?>!) .

Comment: i've edit the question, can you please tell me why the new code doesn't crash ?